# Extending HTMLCanvasElement in Custom Element issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, chromium, custom-element

I can not get a drawing context of a custom canvas element.

```
var customCanvas      = Object.create(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype),
    canvasConstructor = document.registerElement("custom-canvas", { prototype: customCanvas }),
    canvas            = document.createElement("custom-canvas"),
    ctx               = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Is it a bug, omission or something else?

P.S. I search for a solution for chromium-based only browsers.

Comment: I split your var statement into multiple var's; doing that, I get (for the canvasContructor), typeError: document.registerElement is not a function.  Doing a quick google suggests you may need some other library loaded first (or you should probably mention what you're using, but I do appreciate you posted what looks like a good minimum code required to find the error).  [See https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize/issues/110 which then references http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/].  I was using Firefox.closetolastest; you may also want to specify what browser you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I have specified a browser.

Comment: Okay... having same error you're having with Chrome.  Trying to create a webgl context also fails for what it's worth (and in the same console, creating a real canvas and doing realcanvas.getContext("2d") works, which hopefully rules out the question of if for example the 2d context was disabled for some presumably security related concern)

Comment: have you tried adding it into the dom tree?

Comment: Yes I tried many variants, but it is not working.

Comment: I can create HTMLDivElement with a canvas element inside, but I want to use a pure HTMLCanvasElement element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing some points here, when extending a native object you must use the `extends` option:

```
canvasConstructor = document.registerElement("custom-canvas", { prototype: customCanvas, extends: 'canvas' });
```

And you can't create `custom type extensions` directly, so you can't do `createElement("custom-canvas")` you must use the `is` attribute and to do that you must use the `createElement` with two parameters:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas', 'custom-canvas');
//canvas in HTML will be <canvas is="custom-canvas"></canvas>
//<custom-canvas></custom-canvas> is invalid
```

Doing all this way you will be able to use your type extension:

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); //no error :)
```

Comment: I considered this variant, but I need just <custom-canvas></custom>.
Why pure custom element is not working with HTMLCanvasElement?

HTMLDivElement allows to create a pure custom element like <custom-element></custom-element>.

Comment: If you want to use the native `getContext` function, without having to reimplement that in your custom object prototype you MUST do that way. You can't extend a native object and use your custom tag, or you use the original tag and `is`attribute or you create a new component which has a canvas as a child and make the necessary functions available in your prototype.

Comment: How to reimplement the native `getContext`? Edit V8 C++ sources?

Comment: not that way, by reimplementing I meant add a canvas to your component shadow dom, then create a `getContext` function in your custom component prototype and in it you can call your child canvas `getContext` and return the result

Comment: All the same why can not I create a pure custom canvas element with a full functionality? Is it a special idea of blink web-engine developers?

Comment: if you're looking someone to blame you can get their names and contacs here:  http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Comment: For everyone who wondered why the document.registerElement does not work: It has been replaced by window.customElements.define(...) in the latest, official specification (v1).